# Audiosource.GetOutputData() not working in Unity WebGL build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

```
public Text data;
string url = "http://localhost/AudioVisualizer/Spiderman.wav";
float[] samples = new float[1024];
public AudioSource source;
public GameObject L,R;
WWW www;
 IEnumerator Start()
{
    www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    source.clip = www.GetAudioClip();
}
void Update()
{
    source.GetOutputData(samples, 1);
    data.text = samples[0].ToString();

    L.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,Mathf.Abs(samples[0]*2), 1);
    R.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, Mathf.Abs(samples[1]*2), 1);

    if (!source.isPlaying)
        source.Play();
}
```

When I run the above code in editor it runs just fine. But when I take the WebGL build there is no output data.

```
data.text = samples[0].ToString();
```

this line gives 0 as output.

Comment: nope, it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/Manual/webgl-audio.html), `GetOutputData` is **not** supported for WebGL. This is because WebGL does not support threads.There are many other none supported audio features due to this. Only *basic* audio functions are supported.

You will have to manually process the AudioClip yourself. I suggest you check [this](https://github.com/Lakistein/Unity-Audio-Visualizers) project out which is `GetSpectrumData` implementation for WebGL. That will help you implement `GetOutputData` for WebGL.